# How to strip single name from object file on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, symbol-table

I am following some Linux instructions on OS X and am stuck on one line:

```
strip -N main my_file.o
```

The OS X version of `strip` doesn't have an `-N` option and I've read through the man page twice but am just not sure how to do this.

So how do I strip a single name from the symbol table on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the OSX version of `strip` doesn't allow this; the only way therefore is to limit its visibility in code using this on the *declaration*:

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) void MyFunction1();
```

Alternatively you could compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` and use `"default"` in the above `__attribute__` to only expose the symbols you want.

This is a better approach anyway, as it does not require an external build step.

Note: I have found this doesn't work as expected when Objective-C code is introduced into the code base...

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html)